# VbScript error when declaring any variable with its required data types

Tags: vbscript

In my .VBS file, whenever using any such declaration, I am getting error.Why so,any ideae?

```
Option Explicit

Dim vString as String
```

Error is : "Expected end of Statement"

I could not declare any variable with its required data types.

Comment: I found a VBS manual where that syntax Dim <variable> As <subtype> was valid, but not in Microsoft's: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/zexdsyc0(v=vs.84)) the only valid syntax is Dim <variable>. I couldn't find the newest Microsoft manual.

Answer (score 3):

In VBScript there is only variants so it would be `Dim vString` (remove the `As String`)

Comment: Okie..When i declared a Variable as Dim vNumber As Long. Also getting the same error.

Comment: All variable declarations are variants so none need the As xxx.  Just `Dim VarName` no matter what data type you are storing in it.

Comment: Okie..one more query is, Suppose a scenario occurs where i need to store a long number to vNumber. In that case any chance to throw an error?

Comment: Not 100% sure I understand the question fully but you can store any data type (inc long) in vNumber and it wont throw an error.

Comment: There are types in VBScript but it is correct to say it defaults to variants https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281355/get-the-type-of-a-variable-in-vbscript