# Msgbox vbs gave me expected end of the statement

Tags: vbscript

```vb
dim answer = call MsgBox("This will destroy your computer, Do you wish to proceed", 4, "WARNING!") 
If answer = 6 Then
    MsgBox "WORKS!"
End If
```

gave me
expected end of the statement
line 1
char 12

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VbScript error when declaring any variable with its required data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855633/vbscript-error-when-declaring-any-variable-with-its-required-data-types) *(Quick search reveals the issue.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to separate declaring your `answer` variable and assigning the prompt result:

```
Dim answer

answer = MsgBox("This will destroy your computer, Do you wish to proceed", 4, "WARNING!")

If answer = 6 Then
    MsgBox "WORKS!"
End If
```

(and there's no need to `call`)