# VBScript Getting object types in variables

Tags: object, types, vbscript

How can I get an object type in a variable?

For example in VB I can declare this way:

```
Dim tvNode As TreeNode
tvNode = TreeView1.Nodes(1)
tvNode.Remove()
```

That way I can access to the functions to that object.

But in VBScript i do this:

```
Dim tvNode
tvNode = TreeView.Nodes(1)
tvNode.Remove() // Error. Incompatible type - tvNode is type: (name of the node) ???
```

How can I get a node in a variable in VBScript then?

Comment: How did you create `TreeView`? Where does that object come from?

Comment: It's an ActiveX element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was using `Set`. That way I can assign objects to a variable. If I don't use `Set` keyword, it just assigns the string value.

Comment: You should have clarified that your working example was _VB.NET_. In all other VB languages (VB6, VBA, VBScript) `Set` is always required for object assignment.

Comment: I used two examples: One in VB.NET which works as I specified "That way I can access to the functions to that object". And the other example (the language I'm working with) VBScript, which I had the trouble with. Sorry If it wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

Use `TypeName` to get the string representation of the type. There is also `VarType` which returns the VT_ENUM value of the variant type.

See also [Get the type of a variable in VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3281355/291641).

Comment: It returns type `String`. How can I get a TreeView Node type? So I can access to its functions such as remove, add, etc... Thanks.