# Windows Update breaks multipart/form-data ( UPDATE: KB3104002 )

Tags: windows, html, iis, vbscript, forms

I have an image upload page with some text field which has been working for the last 2 years suddenly stopped after Update: KB3104002

```
<form method="POST" action="mrraja.asp" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" name="Form1">
```

After Submit Form Data Not Posted.

Now What Should I Do?

1. Uninstall The Update?
2. Wait and See What Microsoft will Do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uploading a file in classic asp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34181411/uploading-a-file-in-classic-asp) This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34188295/692942) discusses a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has released a hotfix that fixes the multipart form data problem: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3125446

Answer (score 2):

If it's urgent, uninstall the update. I just uninstalled it on five 2008 R2 servers, and now it works well on all of them. You have to restart the server BTW.

I just opened the Control Panel, selected uninstall programs, and then windows updates.

Comment: Be aware that Microsoft reinstalls the update if you don't do anything to prevent it.