# Persits.Upload.1 error '800a0001' Request.BinaryRead failed in classic asp

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, iis-8, image-upload

We have a classic asp application running for a long time but suddenly we are not to save few pages that has option to upload image. It throws the below error:

> Persits.Upload.1 error '800a0001'
>   Request.BinaryRead failed: Unspecified error

We have already installed the ASPUPLOAD key which does not expire.

We have also increased the  AspMaxRequestEntityAllowed limit also which did not work.

```
set upobj = server.CreateObject("Persits.Upload")
upobj.save
```

We are getting error on upobj.save

Comment: It's probably related to this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/34188295/692942

Comment: You can use one of many pure ASP upload scripts, which are easier to debug and fix when failing. I [posted one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874740/pure-asp-upload-with-image-detection) a while ago as well.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a `request.form` somewhere in your code before your `upload.save`.
You cannot access the `request.form` data; only the `upload.form` data